# Destructured object loses reference after being modified

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Object reference is lost after an assignment. Any previous references are no longer relevant.

I have the following:

```
// lib.js

const obj = { prop: { data: { some: 'empty' } } };

function loadObject() {
  obj.prop.data = { some: 'load' };
}

modules.exports = { prop: obj.prop, data: obj.prop.data, loadObject() };
```

and

```
// main.js

const { prop, data, loadObject } = require('./lib');

loadObject();

console.log(prop.data);    // data changed (new reference)
console.log(data);         // data not changed (old reference)
```

How can I modify `data` without losing it's initial reference?

PS:

I have a bunch of files importing this lib and it's relying on that `data`.
I'd rather not replace it to `prop.data` or reread it again in each file that uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replaced `data` with a new object. There’s no way to change everything that references an old object to point to a new object instead, so if you want to keep the exact same API, you have to alter the object in place instead of replacing it – maybe like you did before:

```
// if it’s a single property that’s the same before and after
function loadObject() {
  obj.prop.data.some = 'load';
}

// if the properties before are a subset of the properties after
function loadObject() {
  Object.assign(obj.prop.data, { some: 'load' });
}

// if you need to change the set of properties entirely
function loadObject() {
  for (const key of Object.keys(obj.prop.data)) {
    delete obj.prop.data[key];
  }

  Object.assign(obj.prop.data, { some: 'load' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to different modules systems or objects de-structuring. Please see the following example.

```js
const obj = {prop: {data: {some: 'empty'}}};
const objRef = obj.prop.data;

console.log(objRef);

obj.prop.data.some = 'not empty';

console.log(objRef);

obj.prop.data = {other: 'hello!'};

console.log(objRef);

console.log(obj);
```

Remember that each time that you use the bracket notation to create objects `{}` you are implicitly instantiating a new "independent" object. This is still valid for nested objects like the one in your example. Indeed you have multiple nested references of multiple objects.

The 'name' of the nested object (the key of the parent) acts as a variable that contains the reference of the new object that you are instantiating using `{}`.

I know that this may appear confusing (because it really is), but if you follow the previous snippet I'm sure you will get it. `objRef` keeps a reference of the "independent" object `{some: 'empty'}`, that at the same time is stored as a reference in all the other objects until the primary object `obj`. In this line: `obj.prop.data = {other: 'hello!'};` we are completely erasing `{some: 'empty'}` reference from the primary object, but it is kept in `objRef` which will be the only remaining reference for that object. We are separating `objRef` from `obj`.

- Summary:

Each time you use `{}` -> equivalent to -> `new Object()`

`obj.prop.data.some = 'not empty';` -> Changing property value. Will be seen in all references of `data: {}` object.

`obj.prop.data = {other: 'hello!'};` -> Completely replacing `data: {}` object reference in main object (destroying reference) (still kept in `objRef`).

If it is not clear I could try explaining it in a different way. Please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Having *any* variable seemingly alter itself *on its own* (as a consumer of the library would experience) is quite unintuitive, and is often forbidden by linters for the sake of code clarity - if that sort of logic is needed, consider exporting a *function* which returns the current data instead, eg

```
modules.exports = {
  prop: obj.prop,
  getData: () => obj.prop.data,
  loadObject
};
```

(note that to export the function, you need to just *reference* the function, not call it)

While it would be *possible* to export a mutable binding if you were using ES6 modules, that's not the case here, and wouldn't be a good idea anyway.

Comment: Reassigning `data` here doesn’t change `module.exports.data`, so it looks like it doesn’t do anything at all. (And `obj.data` doesn’t exist.)